# NSURLConnection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge failure response

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

When trying to log in to my app with iOS7 I'm getting a failure response with some description. This is NSLog of NSURLAuthenticationChallenge failureResponse:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xa383570> { URL: <URL> } { status code: 401,headers {
"Content-Length" = 1385;"Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf-8"; 
Date = "Fri, 13 Jun 2014 12:14:24 GMT";  
Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";  
"Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"booo\"";  
"x-errorCode" = 02;  
"x-errorDescription" = "com.idealination.core.server.client.http.ServerException:
Request failed: <URL> Status: CLIENT_ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED  
Error: #Unauthorized :: Invalid userid or password.";
} }
```

and I need that last line to know what error do I get. But when I use iOS6 and iPhone 3gs I get only:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1c507ae0>
```

What should I do to get a response like using iOS7? And why I'm getting a different response?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be looking for the last line, you should be looking for the HTTP Status Code, in this case 401.

```
if(urlResponse.statusCode == 401) { }
```

If you need to convert that into what the status code means as a string use

```
NSString *status = [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:urlResponse.statusCode];
```

Comment: I get the same code if my user is suspended but last line is different. That's why I need that line.

Comment: Maybe I'm catching a server exception in a wrong place? But I can't catch it anywhere else. Or I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @Roo: if you follow the advice above, you can read your "last line" in the `status` variable… hopefully...

Comment: I get status: Unauthorized. But I need details, why is it unauthorized.

Comment: Try logging `urlResponse.headerFields` -- It is an NSDictionary and you may be able to find what you need in there. It is still generally bad practice to do string comparisons for specific error messages as that may change if your server configuration changes. It would be better to use different HTTP status codes or a different custom header with a more specific error code for the different 'unauthorized' scenarios.

Comment: `"x-errorCode" = 02;` or `Status: CLIENT_ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED` may provide more value than `#Unauthorized :: Invalid userid or password.` but I don't know your server setup or if you have control over the response sent by the server here.